# Como importar projeto Maven para Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, maven

Estou tentando importar um projeto do GitHub para meu eclipse, porém não estou tendo sucesso. Seria necessário algum tipo de conversão do projeto?

Estou usando Eclipse Luna, apache-maven-3.3.9.

Comment: Teoricamente não. Como você está fazendo para importar? Que tipo de erro está dando?

Answer (score 5):

Vá em File > Import > Maven > Existing Maven Projects.

Depois é só escolher o diretório e marcar o `pom.xml`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]